# Custom Imagenet Dataset

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, keras, imagenet

I want to make my own custom dataset of imagenet taking 20 classes out of 1000. I am able to convert it to TFRecords format but I want a keras friendly version for it as keras is more flexible for me.

Comment: Keep the images as image files and use `ImageDataGenerator` with `flor_from_directory()`, or create your own generator with some library to open images as arrays, such as PIL, for instance.

Comment: Two options to day that. 1) Move the corresponding images to a directory. Keep track of the names and labels in a csv. Then define a generator and you are good to go. 2) Use the `tf.Dataset` api

Comment: Thats all good, but what about the labels and the xml files which contains the bounding box information for objects in the images (the ones which I gotta train after cropping them).